# Create simple sounds such as 8-bit through code

Tags: audio, c#-4.0, text-to-speech, 8-bit

I need to build a very rigid text to speech generator choosing my own 8 bit sounds per syllable/char but have not found a single piece of code online to do this in C# other than `AudioClip.SetData()` method for creating Sine waves which is not what I need. I need more rough sounds like 8-bit or higher, any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Hard to understand your question, you'd better elaborate.